# SharePoint Data Connection vs. InfoPath

Tags: infopath, data-connection

I’m facing issues with setting up a data connection between SharePoint and InfoPath. 
It works fine without any issues until I publish the form.

The point is that I would like to get a normal username in InfoPath instead of the current format (i:0#.w|domain\firstname.lastname).

Hence I’ve set up a data connection to GetUserProfileByName but unfortunately the system runs in error when I open the form in SharePoint.

See screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you need modify the registry.Please go through the following link.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have admin rights here in the company. Nor coding. Will let the admins know about this article. Thank you!